# Fail to uninstall distutils installed project

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have tried installing new python packages using pip. The installation fails and I get the following error:

> ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'pytz'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

I could determine that there are three builds of pytz version 2016.6.1. 
The version on my machine is build py35_0 and I want to uninstall it. How do I modify the prompt below to uninstall a specific build of a version of a package?

```
$ pip uninstall pytz==2016.6.1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+uninstall+distutils+installed+project

Comment: Problem is the same and has been solved by by brut force. I specifically want to know how to uninstall a specific version and build of a package.

Comment: You cannot uninstall with `pip` what `pip` didn't install.

Comment: The pytz package was installed through pip. The distulise installed package warning is because there are three builds of the pytz version 2016.6.1 on of which is installed on my machine. So the question is still how to tell the machine, that it is build 'py35_0' which is installed and should be deleted.